# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

The command works fine when I execute from command line. However It throws an error when I execute it from shell script

```
rsync -avz -e ssh --exclude-from=rsync.file --rsync-path="sudo rsync" ostnfe/ ubuntu@mask.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/var/www/ostnfe
```

Code from shell script:

```
CMD='rsync -avz -e ssh --exclude-from=rsync.file --rsync-path="sudo rsync"  '$1'/ ubuntu@'$AMZ':/var/www/'$2
$CMD
```

error:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a shell function instead:

```
cmd () {
    rsync -avz -e ssh --exclude-from=rsync.file --rsync-path="sudo rsync"  $1/ ubuntu@$AMZ:/var/www/$2
}

# calling with args
cmd "$1" "$2"

# alternatively, calling through variable without args
VAR='eval cmd "$1" "$2"'
$VAR
```

Less hassle with escaping this way.

Update: Edited cmd() to represent the working solution.

Comment: Thanks. This worked after few modifications. I basically have double quotes only around 'sudo rsync'. Had to remove all other double quotes to make it work.

Comment: @Srik You better never have spaces in your paths then. I find it doubtful that it was necessary to remove the quotes around arguments and it will cause problems with certain arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea to store full command line in a string. Use BASH arrays instead:

```
CMD=(rsync -avz -e ssh --exclude-from=rsync.file "--rsync-path='sudo rsync'" "$1/ ubuntu@$AMZ:/var/www/$2")
"${CMD[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following:

```
CMD=$(echo "rsync -avz -e ssh --exclude-from=rsync.file --rsync-path=\"sudo rsync\"  $1/ubuntu@${AMZ}:/var/www/$2")

$CMD
```

check for any missing or extra space.